# Convert all HTML special chars to UTF-8 in PHP?

Tags: php, special-characters, decode

Can somebody help me?
How can i convert all HTML special chars to UTF-8
Example:

```
Hello&nbsp;Word! P&amp;H
```

convert to:

```
Hello Word! P&H
```

Comment: Have you checked the PHP manual?

Answer (score 23):

Use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) and explicitly specify the charset:

```
$string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
```

for future reference: [PHP string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)

Comment: Would be lovely if SO actually told me the very moment your answer shows up instead of waiting at least 1 whole minute or until I hit *Post Your Answer*...

Comment: @BoltClock yeah, that mechanism is somehow broken, I've noticed too.