# Foreign characters from php to sql

Tags: php, sql

In my scripts you're in an html page, add your name and that gets added to the database via php. However, characters like á are added as something like Ã£.
My database is in utf8. How can I add these characters? áéç etc.

Comment: This should help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775842/convert-all-html-special-chars-to-utf-8-in-php

Comment: ABcDexter that doeant work, returns Ä© instead of é

Comment: Did you set charset for database connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqli_set_charset($con,, "utf8");
Thx to all, I tried alot of stuff but this is what was missing.